# Give anonymous access to a folder under wp-admin folder in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, download, ms-word

I have a folder in wordpress which is located under the wp-admin folder and that folder contains the documents that can be downloaded from the user section.Now when the user downloads the words files using IE-9 and click on the open option from the IE save dialog it gives them a security warning. This problem is solved if I move the folder the root of the website. So I guess there is some access issue is there any way I can provide anonymous access to that folder. I really don't want to change the location of the folder as it will reqiure lots of changes to code and database.

**FYI : This is issue comes only for word files , PDF files in the same folder work fine.**

Comment: this is *really* not recommended. you should use the `/wp-content/` folder unless you want your files to get wiped out on the next upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you cannot access the folder without the username and password even when you try to grab the files of that folder using idm grabber or httrack you will need username and password

Comment: Yes I had to move the folder to the root of the website :)